# How to import different files which each contains xml file together in R?

Tags: r

I have 1000 files which each contains xml file of 1000 papers information. how can i import all these files together in R? it means to say how can i have all 1000000 papers information in R so then I can pars them. i am using:

```
file_names <- list.files("./data")
path <- paste("./data", file_names[1], sep = "/")
raw <- read_xml(path)
article <- xml_children(raw)
```

but this will give each time just one file. i thought of making loop but i couldn't proceed.

Comment: this code each time will give just 1000 papers information, i need all 1000000 papers information together.

Comment: You can use `lapply` to run your `paste` and `read_xml` on each element of `file_names`. This will load each file and the contents as items in a list.

Comment: thank you for your answer, could you please tell me how? as i said i need all 1000000 not just each file separately.

Comment: Read `?lapply`. Something like `articles <- lapply(file_names, function(x) xml_children(read_xml(paste("./data", x, sep = '/'))))`

Comment: i am getting this error then:                                                                                                Error in doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options) : 
  Document is empty [4]